# How can sms messages recieved be identified without senders details?

Tags: authentication

My fiance is receiving random annoying, anonymous SMS Text Messages without any senders details.
I'm not tech savvy and don't know how this can possibly be achieved but is there any way possible of being able to identify the sender without using the Service Center and involving law enforcers, or is there a way to block them?

Comment: Can you provide further information? Are the messages targeting her personally or just seem like an average spam message for mass distribution? What phone is she using? Android, iPhone? What sender info does it show in 'message details'?

Comment: Flash SMS can be used in this way. Aswell as general "number witholding".

Answer (score 3):

Your carrier may be able to tell you what provider was used to send them the SMS, but I'm afraid the sender/caller ID field is just a text field and can be either spoofed or simply not included.

There are a number of carriers happy to charge someone to send an anonymous SMS, making it near impossible without Law Enforcement assistance to track the sender.  Spoofed (and I believe anonymous) SMS was a feature in the Social Engineering Toolkit (SET) and there are Android and iOS apps that will facilitate it as well.